# How to get informations from 3 tables searching by name when the 3 tables are linked by ID

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables that all have different use, and to get user's info I need the ID, but in one of the 3 tables I have access the name, and I wish by entering the name, it give info from the 3 tables (so it uses the ID linked to a name

example of what I'm looking for

Table 1 :

```
ID     1
name   hello
```

Table 2 :

```
ID     1
town   Paris
```

Table 3 :

```
ID     1
loveEating  Bananas
```

And I get in result

```
Id    1
name    hello
town    Paris
loveEating   bananas
```

But I don't search by using the ID but by using the name, so :
`SELECT * FROM table1,table2,table3 WHERE table1.name='hello'`

but it actually use the id that has for name 'hello' and use it in the 3 tables to get all info

Answer (score 0):

You need `join`s:

```
select *
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id join
     table3 t3
     on t1.id = t3.id
where t1.name = ?
```

Comment: It doesn't show me the info from tables 2 and 3, only show me ID and name

Comment: Oh it seems like to work but not exactly like I wanted, I will do another post to make sure it explains exactly what I want